# Magento 1.9 RWD breakpoint for iPad landscape only (SCSS)

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I need the breakpoint for iPad landscape only. I need to make some specific styles or iPad landscape only. How do i set this break (mediaquery) in my SCSS stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add a new mixin in the _breakpoint.scss. Try to add this

```
@mixin bpIpad(){
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){@content}
}
```

this is for ipad 3 and 4, for ipad 1 and 2 the last line should equal one.

Then just @include the mixin in the places you want. ex:

```
@include bpIpad(){
   *Ipad landscape css*
}
```

Comment: I just test. Its compiling now, but unfortunately it has no effect on iPad landscape...?

Comment: are you testing for ipad 3 or 4?

Comment: i am testing on ipad 4

Comment: Ok, try adding the @include bdIpad(){} at the end of the file or at least after  the last reference to the element you are changing the css for. Because if there are css codes of the same hierarchy then the one that appears last gets applied

Comment: no sorry no result.

Comment: Hmm, It worked for me on Ipad simulator

Comment: yes but the problem is on Ipad 4 its still not working... But on (chrome) simulators its working fine, but not on the real Ipad..?